# C++ put results from parser to array

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, parsing

I'm new in C++.

I'd like to know how can I parse a string and put result in an array.

So, imagine I have a string like this:
`104.8  10.9   7.8e-33   2.6e-29      59     248 ..      46     230 ..      20   336 .. 0.87`

It is always the same stile, it means, 14 non `[:space:]` separated by variable number of spaces between then.

I'd like to parse using regex and put this values within an array. Since we know how many matches we can set the array to length 14 `char array[14];`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Instead of using `regex`, I would advise using `std::istringstream` and its [`operator >>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). In particular, pay attention to [this example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt#Example).

Comment: Use a `std::vector` unless you know at compile time that there will be 14 elements.  Then use `std::array`

Comment: @NathanOliver it always have 14 elements.

Comment: @Fureeish thanks, it seems I can use, but I don't understood how to put it in array instead variables, I know would be better if I create the variables as it are (int and double) but since I don't process the variables (just print tab separated in other order) it may be filled as string itself.

Comment: So what's the actual question? How do you provide this string of data? Do you input (always 14) numbers separated by tabulators (note - *tab* is **not** the same as *couple of spaces*, but it wouldn't matter in this case) or do you have them already stored, as in the question, in some `std::string`? Answering this question is likely to allow me to answer the whole question with examples.

Comment: @Fureeish This string is extracted using regex `regex hmmertable("^[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[!\?][[:space:]]+(.+)$");` that ignore all other lines from file with different patterns

Comment: @Fureeish and stored this way `regex_search(line,result,hmmertable);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this data is already contained in a `std::string`, I would propose a solution using [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), in particular, `std::istringstream`.

I can see that you have both real numbers (`104.8`, `7.8e-33`) and strings (`..`), which, I assumed, you also count as separate and valid tokens. In this case, we can divide your data in separate `std::string`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> // std::stringstream family
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string data{"104.8  10.9   7.8e-33   2.6e-29      59" // string concatenation
                     "248 ..      46     230 ..      20   336 .. 0.87"};

    std::istringstream stream{data}; // helper stream

    // Assuming that we're certain that *data* holds exactly 14 tokens, we can
    // use a simple loop. Otherwise we would've needed to check stream's state
    // after every operation.

    std::array<std::string, 14> tokens{};

    for(std::size_t i{0}; i < 14; ++i) {
        stream >> tokens[i];
    }

    // lastly, we can print the results:

    for(const auto& token : tokens) {
        std::cout << token << ' ';
    }
}
```

This will print: `104.8 10.9 7.8e-33 2.6e-29 59248 .. 46 230 .. 20 336 .. 0.87`.

Notice that the additional whitespaces between tokens disappeared.